# If $R \subseteq S$ is a noetherian domain and $\operatorname{ann}_R(S/R) \ne \{0\}$, then $S$ is a finitely generated $R$-module

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

I am working on the following exercise:

> Let $S$ be a commutative ring. If $R \subseteq S$ is a noetherian domain and $\operatorname{ann}_R(S/R) \ne \{0\}$, then $S$ is a finitely generated $R$-module.

I do not see how to do this. I understand that since $R$ is noetherian for every ideal $I \triangleleft R$ there are $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ such that

$$I = a_1R+\dots+a_nR, $$

which is rather close to the desired result. But I do not see how we could now use the condition $\operatorname{ann}_R(S/R) \ne \{0\}$ to prove the claim, maybe we could use that $R$ itself is an ideal? Could you give me a hint?

Comment: This is not true without additional hypotheses.

Comment: Indeed, this fails if we take $S= k[x,y]/(xy)$ and $R = k[x]$.

Comment: @BrianShin: Could you expand on this a bit?

Comment: This is true if $S$ is also a domain.

Comment: @Mohan: Could you please explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Eric Wofsey pointed out, the claim is not true without more hypotheses. For example, it fails if we take $S = k[x,y]/(xy)$ and $R = k[x] \subseteq S$. Indeed, as an $R$ module, we have
$$S\cong R \oplus \left( \bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty R/(x) \right).$$
We find that $S/R$ is annihilated by $x$. Thus $R$ is a Noetherian domain, $\operatorname{ann}_R(S/R) \neq 0$, but $S$ is not a finitely generated $R$-module.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand where $S \cong R \bigoplus \bigl( \bigoplus_{n=1}^{\infty} R/(x) \bigr)$ comes from.

Comment: @3nondatur It comes from the fact that we can write any element of $S$ as a sum $f(x) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n y^n$ where $f(x)$ is a polynomial in one variable, and all but finitely many of the $a_n$s are zero. The $f(x)$ corresponds to the $R$ summand, while each monomial $a_ny^n$ corresponds to the $n$th $R/(x)$ summand.

Answer (score 2):

If $S$ is a domain, let $0\neq a\in \operatorname{Ann}(S/R)$. Then $aS\subset R$ and hence an ideal of $R$ and thus finitely generated. But, $S\cong aS$ by the obvious map and thus $S$ is finitely generated as an $R$-module.